# How best to add Load / Save file to/from a version control system to my Delphi Application

Tags: delphi, svn, version-control

I have an Application that is based on loaded test programs, saved as text-based files in a specific user data folder. All fine. A client has just commented that they would like to have full traceability of changes to such test programs (for ISO9001 etc) and it occured to me that I could provide some kind of checkout / commit mechanism alongside the existing file load / save but which targetted a VCS (say SVN). The problem is that although I use Tortoise SVN for my own development, I've no idea how to write a simple program in Delphi to programmatically access SVN. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at the source code to [DelphiSVN](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphisvn/) it's an OpenTool API application that integrates SVN into the Delphi IDE.

The [SvnClient.pas](http://delphisvn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/delphisvn/trunk/src/SvnClient.pas?revision=69&view=markup) in that project looks like an excellent way to call the [SVN API](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch08s02.html)
with the low level wrapper for the API in [svn_client.pas](http://delphisvn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/delphisvn/trunk/src/svn_client.pas?revision=67&view=markup)

Comment: +1 mentioning SvnClient.
This is an excellent Delphi open source project. However, SVN API is a little bit complicated and you need to dive deep in some rules and behaviours of SVN that are not seen in TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 2):

[Using the SVN APIs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch08s02.html) seems like a good starting point.

Presumably you could also call the binaries directly e.g.

```
system( "svn checkout something" );
```

Although the simplest that appraoch should be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: system() does not exist in Delphi, maybe you mean shellexecute